# How to estimate contents of a matrix used as a multiplier in matrix multiplication, if dimensions and contents of other matrices are known?

Tags: python, numpy

Looking to understand how to estimate the contents of a matrix used in matrix multiplication, given the following information:

- The product of the matrix multiplication
- The other matrix used as a multiplier
- Dimensions of the 'missing' matrix

For example, if a 1x3 matrix is multiplied by a 3x4 matrix to give a 1x4 matrix product:

```
matrix_A = np.array([10, 20, 70])
matrix_B = np.array([[50, 25, 10, 15], 
                     [10, 60, 20, 10], 
                     [ 5, 10, 80,  5]])

matrix_C = np.matmul(a, b)
```

The product of this multiplication, matrix_C, will hold the array:

```
array([1050, 2150, 6100, 700])
```

But if we were to know only `matrix_A` and `matrix_C`, as well as the 3x4 dimensions of `matrix_B`, is there a way to estimate the numerical contents of `matrix_B` using numpy?

Comment: What do you mean by _estimate_?

Comment: I mean that ideally, I would like to find the contents of the missing multiplier matrix - not sure if it is possible.

Comment: This is not a problem with a unique solution.  For example ```array([[ 1.94444444,  3.98148148, 11.2962963 ,  1.2962963 ],
       [ 3.88888889,  7.96296296, 22.59259259,  2.59259259],
       [13.61111111, 27.87037037, 79.07407407,  9.07407407]])``` is also a valid `B`.

Comment: You can find _some_ matrix B. The problem is that there is no unique matrix B that satisfies A x B = C. You can easily see it is an underconditioned problem like this: you have twelve unknowns (elements in B) and four equations (one per element in C, each "A times column in B" multiplication). There are some trivial ways you can find a "valid B", like making the first row equal to C divided by the first element of A (assuming it's not zero), and the rest of rows zero. But there is no way to know "which B" it came from.

Comment: I see. Many thanks. Was hoping to see if there was an existing numpy method that might help with finding said different valid possibilities for the missing matrix - I am new to numpy. Will think about it further. Thanks again.